# Cassandra Embedded mode

Tags: cassandra

Can we use Cassandra embedded mode for production use?.

I have tested both the mode in single node.
Performance in embedded mode is slightly less as compared to stand alone mode.
What  will be the reason behind it? 
Is there any other side effect by using embedded mode in production.

Answer (score 6):

I would not recommended this for several reasons

1. Same JVM means only one Heaps
2. Same JVM means GC from App effects C* response time
3. Running a multi-node configuration would require multiple running apps
4. When the app shuts down the C* node shuts-down as a well
5. Impossible to restart or upgrade C* without shutting down app as well

Unless you have a very particular use case for this I would definitely NOT recommended using the embedded mode.

Comment: Would it make sense to use Cassandra in embedded mode to store large amount of time series data on a (GUI) client? I was considering H2, but think Cassandra would be a better fit for performance reasons.

Comment: I doubt Cassandra would be better. Cassandra is best when you have large volumes of incoming data that need to be highly available or need cross dc replication. It's not very full featured as an embedded db and the performance could easily be beaten by a solely in-mem embedded DB living in your app.

Comment: Well, when it comes to in-mem DB performance, that's not what they discovered in this fairly recent paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319157816300453 that compares performance of popular in-memory databases, including Cassandra. They say: `H2 clearly provides the worst read performance.` Edit: they didn't mention if they used H2 in the embedded mode, maybe not, could this be the reason?

Comment: Cassandra isn't an in memory database ... and anywhere that Redis is slower than Cassandra should definitely be considered dubious ...